# Android - Show App is in Development mode

Tags: android, android-theme

I have a mobile commerce app and I would like to show in the app that it is running in Development mode or Production mode so that there is no chance of a member of our team accidentally placing an order on the production server.

I had the foresight to derive all my `Activity` class from a super `Activity` class where I can add code that will run in all the app's activities. I tried to change the theme here and although the theme changes, I don't  quite know how best to indicate the difference.

I would change the text in the `TitleBar` but my app doesn't have one. The next idea was to change background color of the entire app but some activities have a default color in the layout.

Ideally, I would like text somewhere on the screen saying something like 'dev mode' but I realize that this might be pretty hard to do so I'm up for interesting suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

How about using a ViewStub for development mode?

You can place a ViewStub in each of your layouts where you want to indicate development mode. Your ViewStub can just hold a simple TextView of some sort that says "Development Mode", kind of like a Title bar.

In the code-behind get the reference to the ViewStub and pass it into that common method that runs in each activity. If you are in development mode, inflate the ViewStub.

Take a look at this: 
http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/layout-tricks-stubs.html

Comment: Ohhhhh... each and every one of the layouts... that's painful. However, it does give me an idea